# Connecting 18650 batteries in parallel?

Tags: mosfet, battery-charging, lithium-ion, solar-charge-controller

I have encountered a bizarre situation, i bought two 18650 batteries each of 3.7V, 2200mAh, im using a Tp4056 based charger with battery protection which has DW01A and FS8205 to protect the battery from UV, Over discharge etc. For charging these batteries, the Rprog resistor in Tp4056 charger is set at 1.2k for a charge rate at 1A.

Everything was fine, when i connected these batteries, but after some time the FS8205 MOSFET, has burnt up badly it had bursted to smokes, did not understand why this scenario arised, i'm sure i've checked the battery polarity twice before i connected.

Hope maybe some of you have experienced this scenario and what could be the possible reason for this?

Thanks.

Comment: The TP4056 is only meant to be used with single cells. Are you using two TP4056s?

Comment: @Felthry "in parallel". And it is a mosfet in protection circuit that gets burned

Comment: No I'm not using, I'm connection 2 cells in parallel.

Comment: I'm connecting two cells in parallel, and using only one TP4056 IC.

Comment: Do you have protection on each cell? I recall telling you on some other thread that you need one of those DW01A on each cell

Comment: No I'm using a common protection IC for both the cells.

Comment: Maple, could you explain me why this situation arises?

Comment: [off-topic] at first I was like: wow, 18 kilobatteries in parallel… =)

Comment: No schematic? VTC.

Comment: @Shiv not without seeing your circuit first. Without that I can only recommend checking all connections first (especially MOSFET pins), making sure your two cells have same voltage before connecting them in parallel, and monitoring all voltages/currents at least once for entire charge cycle

Comment: @Shiv add the schematic of your circuit to your question, please.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0HLO.png

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist That has chargers in parallel, not cells. The question seems to imply single charger for 2P battery.

Comment: I wonder if Shiv knows how to measure temperature rise and current to verify where the fault lies before it goes up in smoke. There is a current sense R for the purpose of measuring current.  Temperature with a thermometer will do if nothing better.

Comment: @TonyEEroclscientist,i will try to measure the temp and current as well, but i'm feared that I had to repeat the same scenario again.

Answer (score 3):

You have two 2200mAh batteries parallel to make a total of 4.4Ah. This will take over 4 hours to charge at 1A. The Tp4056 is a *linear* charging IC which limits current by dropping voltage, resulting in high power dissipation. To prevent burning up it throttles the current back when reaching ~75°C. Without forced cooling the entire charging module will run at an elevated temperature, stressing other parts such as the protection controller and FET.

Furthermore the TP4056 achieves current regulation by pulsing on and off, relying on external resistances in the circuit to limit peak current. Two cells in parallel have half the internal resistance of a single cell. Therefore the peak battery current will be higher than usual, causing higher loss in the protection FET.

The combination of high peak current and prolonged high temperature might cause a weak FET to fail. Considering the dubious quality of these modules the chance of random failure is probably also quite high. You may have just been unlucky and a replacement module might work fine. However for reliability it might be better to replace it with a more efficient switch-mode charger that runs cooler.

[Review of TP4056 Charger](https://lygte-info.dk/review/Review%20Charger%20TP4056%20UK.html)
[image]

Comment: "charging module will run at an elevated temperature, stressing other parts" how would high t of Tp4056 stress other parts? "achieves current regulation by pulsing on and off" would you mind giving a link to this info? I could not find anything about this. The protection FET is rated 6A continuous and has RDS of 30 mOhm. I doubt even "higher than usual" current will stress it much.

Comment: 6A is the **absolute maximum** rating. Operating it at that current will dramatically reduce reliability. In a protection circuit the two FETs are wired in series for a total resistance of 60 milliOhms or more (20% higher at 150ºC junction temperature), so it would dissipate 0.5W at ~3A. On a 'minimum thermal pad' the thermal resistance is 208ºC/W, so at 3A it would be burning hot. That's at 25ºC ambient. Add more heat from the TP4056 and it would be even less capable. At 1A it _should_ be fine, but that is assuming the specs are accurate and the part meets them.